# Swift 2.2 Selector with multiple arguments - actually passing in

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use a selector, but I need to pass in the arguments
I understand the syntax follows:

`#selector(class.method(_:paramName:))`

but i need to actually pass in parameters. How do I do this?

Here's my attempt:

```
exploreTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.showViewWithIdentifier(_:exploreView,id:"explore")))
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the parameters, that's not how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to selectors, selector is just a method name, nothing else. You are not calling the method so you cannot pass parameters.
Just call the necessary code inside your tap handler.

```
func onTap() {
   MainViewController.showViewWithIdentifier(exploreView, id:"explore")
}
```

and then

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
```

Comment: This is a good work-around. I ended up having to create a bunch of one-line methods for each case. Still works tho. thanks

Comment: @LukePatterson It's not a workaround, it's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: It's a solution to an impossible problem.

Comment: @LukePatterson You can wrap `UITapGestureRecognizer` in a custom class that will take a closure instead of a selector.